# Transfer custom web template to new site, features not activated-Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, feature-activation, web-template

I have a web template created in site collection A and have been requested to copy that web template to site collection B. To do this, I downloaded the web template solution by going to the solutions gallery on the top level site on Site Collection A and saving the .wsp file to my local machine. I then uploaded the .wsp file to the solution gallery on Site Collection B.

Now when I try to create a new subsite using the custom web template on Site Collection B I get the following errors.
[image]

I've attempted to activate the features listed using the JSOM on both the web feature collection and the site feature collection but I get errors that the features are not installed in the farm. The weird thing is why does the "applying web template" error show that the features are "not activated" when the features aren't even installed? What can be done about this? Do I need to have the server admin (also fairly new to sharepoint) activate/install these features through other means?

Comment: For Online: It's about Office 365 Plans, imho. Had same problem, features were exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see these features available (activated or not) in the list of site collection features? If not, then you need to install the necessary solutions to get these features. The web template is only checking for the dependencies as certain features activated. It doesn't check if they are installed in the first place! I am assuming installing these dependencies (features) is outside the scope of your work and you can have them installed n activated as pre-requisites to your work.

Comment: I don't see them in the list of features on any of the Site Features pages at all, the Site A/B top level site nor on the original site that the web template came from. Where is this dependency coming from? We haven't been deploying sites from custom solutions, just the out of the box stuff. Is this a problem with how the Site B collection was created?

Comment: Both the features are scoped to Site Collection level. So, you will find them in the Site Collection features and not site features. Also, both these mentioned features are provided by SharePoint. Please have a look at this   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/razi/archive/2013/10/28/listing-all-sharepoint-2013-features-including-name-title-scope-id-and-description.aspx. You can use PowerShell to check availability or install / activate them.

Comment: I feel terrifically dumb. I saw "site features" on the administration page and immediately stopped looking, didn't even see the "site collection features" link. Problem solved thank you very much!